# What music-based dungeon crawler game is this?

Tags: game-identification

I found this gameplay video, but I do not see any name of the game title in the comments section, or the title or description of the video.

Comment: The first item in the related video says "Crypt of the Necrodancer." Maybe that's it?

Comment: @JeffMercado My related video feed shows Mortal Kombat X suggestions - based on what I've been viewing the last few hours.

Comment: This is the [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ImZjdg5dEs). You don't necessarily have to look at the first related video, it will be scattered throughout the list.

Comment: In cases such as this you can try viewing the link in incognito mode, so that your history has no effect on the related videos. (this tip works in many situations, including buying airline tickets)

Comment: @JeffMercado I don't see that name showing up anywhere in my suggested view list :(

Comment: Incidentally it *is* Crypt of the Necrodancer, and it's a cracking good game.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the video is dead ([relevant meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/how-should-a-game-identification-question-that-no-longer-has-a-valid-artifact-be/15517#15517))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This indie game is called "Crypt of the Necrodancer".

This game is quite new, being released in late April 2015, and has achieved very high ratings, 10/10 on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/247080/) and 4.5/5 on [Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/crypt-of-the-necrodancer).

As you noted it's a rogue-like, (proceduraly-generated) dungeon crawler but incorporates elements from rhythm games. For instance the player cannot perform actions such as moving or attacking unless they perform the action in time with the beat of the music.

Comment: Unless you play as the character that lets you make your own rhythm, of course!

Comment: Can't recommend this game enough.